# Export beamer slides to powerpoint editable format

Tags: latex, export, powerpoint, edit, beamer

I usually prepare my talks using powerpoint, where I explaing programs, pseudocodes, etc. Recently I was thinking about creating text-only, code-only and pseudocode-only slides with beamer and then exporting them somehow to powerpoint where I modify them to add figures or some minor details for polishing the presentation, which are usually hard to do with beamer. Sometimes it is also a problem when I work in a shared presentation with a colleague that only knows powerpoint and who has to make minor final modifications.

I googled a bit around and found that beamer can export to PDF or PS but not to powerpoint. I wonder anyway if you know some possibility of conversion from beamer to on-screen editable powerpoint - openffice impress.

Comment: I don't think this is possible. What do you do in powerpoint that you can't in beamer ?

Comment: please I do not want to initiate a thread beamer-vs-powerpoint; I just think that beamer is very good at formatting text, equations, code, etc, but for animations powerpoint is way better

Comment: If you could convert to powerpoint/ooimpress, you would lose the formatting quality of latex which is why you used it in the first place.

Comment: I do not care if I lose a bit of quality if I can then easily add animations or even better, send the presentation to a colleague whom with I collaborate

Comment: @flow: I think you will get better results in tex.stackexchange.com. I flagged for moving the question there (you might do the same, to signal your consent).

Comment: I posted it also to tex exchange

Comment: Link to this one, duplicate https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/21986/13173 I think this thread here should be deleted because it is a complete duplicate of the other thread

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can you export from beamer as ascii text?
PowerPoint can open/import from plain text files as well as the usual app-specific files.
For example, put this into a text file (replace  with literal tab chars), then start PPT and open the file, watch what happens:

```
This will be the title of your first slide
<tab>First bullet point, Level 1
<tab><tab>Level 2 bullet point
This will be the title of your second slide
And the title of your third slide
<tab>With more
<tab><tab>Bullets
<tab><tab>To drive Ed Tufte mad
```

And that's all.

Comment: one can probably do that, but I think it would be useless; I would then prefer to start wotking with powerpoint from scratch

Comment: I see my post got reformatted into oblvion.  Basically, each new line becomes the title of a new slide unless it's got one or more tab characters at the beginning of the line. If it has one tab, it becomes a first level bullet; two tabs, a second level bullet and so on.  If you have a lot of text in beamer and it's easy to export in this format, then it'd save a little time.  Otherwise, as you say ... easier just to do it in PPT to begin with.